# .netframework ref .netframework dll that ref .netcore via nuget packages

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, .net-framework-version

So long story short, new code is being built in .netcore 1.6

We have a metric ton load of stuff develop in everything from .netframework 3.5 to 4.6.2

The new stuff needs to be referenced by the old stuff, and vice versa. Supposedly this is possible according to microsoft.

However... if I make a new csproj targeting .netframework 461, I can get it to use nuget packages created by a solution with project targeting .netcore 1.6

Now if I have another csproj/dll that targets .netframework 461, targeting the pre-mentioned .netframework 461 (that is using nuget packages to get .netcore 1.6 code), the second .netframework 461 is throwing an error I'll list below.

So:

Project A = .netcore 1.6 3rd party tool that uses Serilog

Project B = .netframework 461

Project C = .netframework 461

Project B loads Project A via nuget package

Project C loads Project B via 'add reference' old school dll.

If I execute Project B as a console app, all code in Project B and A execute correctly. If I then change Project B to a library, and have Project C reference Project B as an "add reference" dll, and attempt to call code in Project B, I get the error:

```
=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
(Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///[BLOCKED OUT ON PURPOSE]
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration, Version=1.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: [BLOCKED OUT ON PURPOSE]\ConsoleAppTest.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Redirect found in application configuration file: 4.0.0.0 redirected to 4.1.0.0.
LOG: Post-policy reference: System.Runtime, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///[BLOCKED OUT ON PURPOSE]/System.Runtime.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///[BLOCKED OUT ON PURPOSE]/System.Runtime/System.Runtime.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///[BLOCKED OUT ON PURPOSE]/bin/Debug/System.Runtime.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///[BLOCKED OUT ON PURPOSE]/bin/Debug/System.Runtime/System.Runtime.EXE.

   at [BLOCKED OUT ON PURPOSE].Connection.Connect()
   at ConsoleAppTest.Program.Main(String[] args) in [BLOCKED OUT ON PURPOSE]\ConsoleAppTest\Program.cs:line 14
```

Unfortunately downgrading/upgrading  Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration, Version=1.1.2.0 is not an option. I have to use that version because a 3rd party library uses it by utilizing Serilog.

I tried making Project B a nuget package.  So that everyone would reference everyone else using nuget packages. However in vs 2017 the "package" tab does not appear in the properties window for Project B.  I downloaded a 3rd party nuget package creator and I probably didn't use it correctly but I couldn't get it to work that way either.

Comment: There's not such thing as .Net Core 1.6. Do you mean .Net Standard 1.6?

Comment: Also, I don't see the actual exception message. Could you include that?